# could not receive all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugUnitTestApkCopy'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting following error when I try to run app in android studio.

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugUnitTestApkCopy'.
>   Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>        Required by:
>            MyFirstAppp:app:unspecified
>   Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/75.126.118.188] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 0):

May you have proxy limitations or connections issues that won't let gradle connect and compile JUnity.

You could **remove** this line from dependences at build.gradle (module: app)

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ramos for your reply. I have got another solution of this error. Here are the steps to solve the error.

```
      1. download junit-4.12.jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12
      2. Then put junit-4.12.jar into your <project>/app/libs/ directory
      3. Right click on your project and then select "Open Module Settings". Then go to tab "Dependencies"
      4. From "Dependencies" tab, select and delete junit-4.12.jar
      5. Then add junit-4.12.jar from your <project>/app/libs directory
      6. Then rerun your project.
```

Thanks